# How to know if a Contact from SugarCRM is opt out from emails using REST API?

Tags: php, api, rest, sugarcrm

I am currently creating a script to synchronize users from our company's website onto sugarcrm.

I'm using this REST API to communicated with SugarCRM (the answer is not necessarely on this library, I understand how REST works):
http://github.com/asakusuma/SugarCRM-REST-API-Wrapper-Class/

The synchronization is mostly working except I need to also synchronise email opt outs. And the opt_out option doesn't seem to be a normal field.

How can I find out via REST if a Contact I'm fetching is opt_out or not ?
Also how can I set a Contact to be or not opt out ?

Thank you

PS: I want to do it via REST API, not via accessing the database, which isn't clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this blog post for some clues on how to do this:

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2010/11/16/howto-lookup-email-address-related-to-a-record-via-web-services/

Comment: Thank you!
Any idea on how to change if its opt-in or opt-out on a Contact via REST or SOAP ?

Comment: Actually I figured it out myself. I fetched the 'id' field of email address as shown in your link. And then I send a "set" request to update the module EmailAddresses and set opt_out to 1 or 0.